# Statement to categorise academic students

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a nested IF/AND statement to categorise academic students into focus groups. The conditions I have to meet are as follows:

1. BD="Yes" and AY is =>5 or
2. BD="Yes" and AY is =<5 or
3. BG="Yes" and BF="No" and AY is =>5 or
4. BF="Yes" and BG="No" and AY is =>5 or
5. BG="Yes" and BF="No" and AY is =<5 or
6. BF="Yes" and BG="No" and AY is =<5 or
7. X="D" and Y="D" and AY is =<4 or
8. any other result

I've tried a few different ways but can't sculpt anything into one statement.

Comment: Update your post with what you have tried already, even if it didn't work. It will help us understand the logic.

Comment: Where is the pictured spreadsheet? Why a single statement?

Comment: What I've tried already is just simple =If(and etc etc, I don't profess to being the most able when it comes to these formulas

Comment: Duly Noted, and changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't post in comments (don't have enough reputation). Probably, you need several `countifs()` formulas:

1 BD="Yes" and AY is =>5 : `=countifs(BD:BD,"Yes",AY:AY,">=5")`

2 BD="Yes" and AY is =<5 : `=countifs(BD:BD,"Yes",AY:AY,"<=5")`

3 BG="Yes" and BF="No" and AY is =>5 : 
`=countifs(BG:BG,"Yes",BF:BF,"No",AY:AY,">=5")`

4 BF="Yes" and BG="No" and AY is =>5 : `=countifs(BG:BG,"No",BF:BF,"Yes",AY:AY,">=5")`

5 BG="Yes" and BF="No" and AY is =<5 : `=countifs(BG:BG,"Yes",BF:BF,"No",AY:AY,">=5")`

6 BF="Yes" and BG="No" and AY is =<5 : `=countifs(BG:BG,"No",BF:BF,"Yes",AY:AY,"<=5")`

7 X="D" and Y="D" and AY is =<4 : `=countifs(X:X,"D",Y:Y,"Yes",AY:AY,"<=4")`

Nested IF:
`=IF(AND($BD2="Yes",$AY2>=5),1,IF(AND($BD2="Yes",$AY2<=5),2,IF(AND($BG2="Yes",$BF2="No",$AY2>=5),3,IF(AND($BF2="Yes",$BG2="No",$AY2>=5),4,IF(AND($BG2="Yes",$BF2="No",$AY2<=5),5,IF(AND($BF2="Yes",$BG2="No",$AY2<=5),6,IF(AND($X2="D",$Y2="D",$AY2<=4),7,8)))))))`

Comment: Thanks for this Alex, unfortunately I need to combine all the statements into 1 cell due to space and requirements constaints.

Comment: Then your can simply sum countifs' results in one cell. For example:
`=countifs(BD:BD,"Yes",AY:AY,">=5")+countifs(BD:BD,"Yes",AY:AY,"<=5")+countifs(BG:BG,"Yes",BF:BF,"No",AY:AY,">=5")+...`

Comment: What I'm wanting the result to look like is not a sum but to identify what focus group that particular student belongs to, dependant on which statement fits. if that clarifies things a little

Comment: Like this? formula for the second row:

`=IF(AND($BD2="Yes",$AY2>=5),1,IF(AND($BD2="Yes",$AY2<=5),2,IF(AND($BG2="Yes",$BF2="No",$AY2>=5),3,IF(AND($BF2="Yes",$BG2="No",$AY2>=5),4,IF(AND($BG2="Yes",$BF2="No",$AY2<=5),5,IF(AND($BF2="Yes",$BG2="No",$AY2<=5),6,IF(AND($X2="D",$Y2="D",$AY2<=4),7,8)))))))`

Comment: Exactly how doesn't it work for you? Does it always return 8 or incorrect groups, or something else?

Comment: I'm getting an error when entering it (Copy and paste) i think it's failing when it comes to the third if statement. Can the And/IF work with specifying two logical arguments as specifics and a third if the cells is over a value

Comment: Oops. 
When you copy a formula from comments, Stackoverflow adds an invisible character for each line break (((
Please see the correct formula at the end of my original answer. Copy/paste it, and you will see that it works fine.

Comment: Brilliant, Working Perfectly Thanks Alex. I Owe you one!